How to Resolve Missing Std. Error, z-value, and p-value in Multinomial Logit Model with Interaction Terms in R?
I am trying to estimate a Multinomial Logit model with an interaction effect in R. The interaction is between:
group (an individual-specific variable), and
productarea (an alternative-specific variable).
To create the interaction term, I used the interaction() function. However, when I include the interaction variable in the Multinomial Logit model, the results show NA for the standard errors (Std. Error), z-values (z-value), and p-values (Pr(>|z|)).
Here is an example of the output:
Model Coefficients: 
                  Estimate Std. Error z-value Pr(>|z|)
productareaB   -0.34601245         NA      NA       NA
price           0.00083933         NA      NA       NA
interaction1.A -0.33561221         NA      NA       NA
interaction0.B -0.68162466         NA      NA       NA
interaction1.B  0.33561221         NA      NA       NA`

Without the interaction term, the model works fine, and the standard errors, z-values, and p-values are correctly displayed.
My Question:
How can I include the interaction effect and get the full results (with standard errors, z-values, and p-values) in the Multinomial Logit model? Is there a specific way to handle interactions between individual-specific and alternative-specific variables in this context?
#required package
library(logitr)

# data
mydata <- structure(list(choice_set = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 
6, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 
5, 5, 6, 6, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6), partID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), group = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), choice = c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0), alternative = c("1", "2", "1", 
"2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", 
"1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", 
"2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", 
"1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", 
"2", "1", "2", "1", "2"), productarea = c("A", "B", "A", "B", 
"A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", 
"A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", 
"B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", 
"A", "B", "A", "B"), price = c(1955, 2300, 2300, 1955, 2300, 
2645, 2645, 2300, 2645, 1955, 2300, 2300, 1955, 2300, 2300, 1955, 
2300, 2645, 2645, 2300, 2645, 1955, 2300, 2300, 1955, 2300, 2300, 
1955, 2300, 2645, 2645, 2300, 2645, 1955, 2300, 2300, 1955, 2300, 
2300, 1955, 2300, 2645, 2645, 2300, 2645, 1955, 2300, 2300, 1955, 
2300, 2300, 1955, 2300, 2645, 2645, 2300, 2645, 1955, 2300, 2300
), obsid = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 
9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 
17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 19, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 22, 23, 23, 24, 24, 
25, 25, 26, 26, 27, 27, 28, 28, 29, 29, 30, 30)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 11L, 12L, 21L, 22L, 31L, 32L, 41L, 42L, 51L, 52L, 3L, 4L, 
13L, 14L, 23L, 24L, 33L, 34L, 43L, 44L, 53L, 54L, 5L, 6L, 15L, 
16L, 25L, 26L, 35L, 36L, 45L, 46L, 55L, 56L, 7L, 8L, 17L, 18L, 
27L, 28L, 37L, 38L, 47L, 48L, 57L, 58L, 9L, 10L, 19L, 20L, 29L, 
30L, 39L, 40L, 49L, 50L, 59L, 60L), class = "data.frame")

# Estimating Models with Interactions

mydata$interaction <- interaction(mydata$group, mydata$productarea)
summary(logitr(
  data = mydata,
  outcome = "choice",
  obsID = "obsid",
  panelID = "partID",
  pars = c('productarea', 'price','interaction')))


Usually, when this kind of thing happens, it's because the model is overspecified (too complex for the relatively small dataset you have) and it is not converging. Your options are essentially either (1) to simplify the model until it converges, for example by removing the interaction term, as you have done, or (2) switch to a Bayesian approach, in which you can use regularizing priors to provide enough information to constrain the parameter estimates and enable the model to converge.

I agree about the risk of overspecification. Furthermore, the logitr() function has some very demanding requirements for data formatting. I wonder if there might be a problem with that. Could you instead use multinomial regression provided by the multinom() function in the nnet package? Also, your model didn't include an individual term for group to accompany the group:productarea interaction. That's usually not a good idea, although it probably doesn't account for your particular problem.
